# Can I return an image instead of a string in this mvc3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This works perfectly for what I am doing except one thing -- I'd like it to return a thumbnail image instead of a string. Is this possible in mvc3. This is my controller and I'm using an Ajax.ImageActionLink. I am a novice and am muddling through things. Thanks.

```
    public string ThankYou()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
        return "Serenity Equine Rescue";
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like C. Did you mean C#?

Comment: Are you wanting to return the binary data of an image, or a path to an image file?

Comment: It's so hard for me to articulate because I don't know all the terminology. I just keep at it until I get it to work. I have a clickable image on the view page and when clicked runs a animated gif with Ajax.ImageActionLink. The system thread closes it when finished and puts in the text "Serenity Equine Rescue" in place of the original clickable image. I just want that image back after the gif goes away. I'm using the text right now so it works. This is c# in a mvc3 project.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is action, the you just use one of `FileResult` methods on controller class that you're in.

And BTW action methods should not return anything but `ActionResult` and its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult ThankYou()
{
    byte[] imageData = ...
    return File(imageData, "image/png");
}
```

or if it is not a dynamic image:

```
public ActionResult ThankYou()
{
    string imageFile = @"c:\images\foobar.png";
    return File(imageFile, "image/png");
}
```

and then you could use an `<img>` tag to display this image:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ThankYou")" alt="some image" />
```

Comment: I have to have it very clear. This connects to my view page where I have this                                                                                                                                     <div id="THC-01"><div id="ThankYou">
@Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Content/Media/Images/thankyoucards/Thanks01-tn.jpg", "Thank you!", "ThankYou", new {id = "THC-01"}, new AjaxOptions()
{
            UpdateTargetId="ThankYou",
            HttpMethod="GET",
            LoadingElementId="divLoading"
        })
        
</div></div>   I want a thumbnail to return not a line of text on view.

Comment: I beg you pardon? I am not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: Darin's answer seems legit.  On the other hand, why not just return the path to the image in an <IMG/> tag?  Less bandwidth is being used.

Comment: @Moses - There would be no difference in bandwidth

Comment: @AndrewBurgess - Or it would because of compression from IIS and the served MIME type? perhaps? maybe?  Not sure if MIME compression is observed through the *Result in MVC.

Comment: @Moses - It should be identical (can't really compress the PNG more). The server has to go through a full MVC request lifecycle though when serving it this way instead of just delivering a static file

Comment: Incase IIS compression comes up again - http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression